# Why for in operator is displaying index values instead of actual objects in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with three person objects.I am trying to print each object using for in operator, instead of object i am getting index value(0, 1, 2) of each object.The following is my code.Any help would be appreciate.

```
        var persons = [{
                name: "user1",
                password: "password1"
            }, {
                name: "user2",
                password: "password2"
            }, {
                name: "user3",
                password: "password3"
            }]

            for (var person in persons) {
                console.log(person)
            }
```

Comment: Try use `forEach`

Comment: Giving the index/key names is what `for...in` does - see the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more info. You want [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or, as @hadiJz said, [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to angular, this is a JavaScript issue.
The `for...in` keyword loops over keys in an object, not the values. This is usually used with actual objects, not arrays:

```js
let person = {
  name: "user1",
  password: "password1"
}

for (k in person) {
  console.log('person[' + k + '] =', person[k])
}
```

To loop over an array, you could use a native regular `for` or the array's `forEach` method:

```js
let people = [{
  name: "user1",
  password: "password1"
}, {
  name: "user2",
  password: "password2"
}]

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; ++i) {
  console.log('people[' + i + '] =', JSON.stringify(people[i]))
}

people.forEach((person, idx) => {
  console.log('person ' + idx + ' =', JSON.stringify(person))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `forEach`

```
  angular.forEach(persons,function(person,key){
    console.log(key);
   })
```